# Swift error al ejecutar la app: dyld: Library not loaded:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Cuando ejecuto la app tanto en el simulador como en un dispositivo, la misma se cierra y me muestra el siguiente error:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DatePickerDialog.framework/DatePickerDialog
  Referenced from: /Users/bimo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/930D181E-3A41-4086-AA01-FEF52B640845/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/906578C2-C547-4917-A1FE-9D9778E67857/Bimo.app/Bimo
  Reason: image not found

He probado varias cosas, borre todos los pods y los volví a instalar, borre el framework que esta bajo la pestaña de general y lo volví a agregar.
Borre la carpeta de derivedData y volvi a indexar todo de nuevo y me sigue dando el error.

Inclusive me cree un usuario nuevo en la Mac, bajé el repo de nuevo y el error no se va.

Pensé que podía ser un error de certificados, pero entre con otro usuario y da el mismo error.
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: En este link esta la solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project

Answer (score 1):

Ya probaste borrando la derived data, limpiando el proyecto y volviendo a construir?

Comment: Si, lo probe y no anduvo :(